# PostgreSQL get yesterday by calling CURRENT_DATE

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Running "SELECT CURRENT_DATE" in PostgreSQL returns yesterday in my case. Do you know a reason for this? There are alternative options like "LOCALTIMESTAMP". But i do not find something like "LOCALDATE"...

Comment: Postgres takes the date & time from the operating system, so I guess the computer on which Postgres is running has the wrong date.

Comment: maybe the clock on the database server is wrong or the timezone is set to somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast `localtimestamp` to `date` to get the current date in your session time zone:

```
SELECT CAST(localtimestamp AS date);
```

Comment: i already tried this. On "SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP" i get the correct date and time. But "SELECT CAST(localtimestamp AS date)" is again yesterday....

Comment: I find that hard to believe. The function used to cast `timestamp without time zone` to `date` is `IMMUTABLE`, so it doesn't depend on any settings. Can you run `SELECT localtimestamp, CAST(localtimestamp AS date), date(localtimestamp);` and show the result? What do you get for `\dC timestamp` in `psql`?

Comment: as i said for localtimestamp i get the correct date, for CAST(localtimestamp AS date), date(localtimestamp) yesterday. How should i run "\dC timestamp" ? Sorry im new in the field

Comment: Sorry, but I stubbornly refuse to believe that. Are you sure you are using PostgreSQL?

Comment: yes :) i saw the wrong dates on console.log by a nodeJS script. By running the script for an insert on the database, correct dates are used... i dont get this.

Comment: So what do you get when you run `select current_date` inside **`psql`**?

Answer (score 1):

I think, the reason for this is your server is difference country, this mean time offset is difference. I have the same problem and I have been selected like this:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + interval time offset
```

For example my Server at England, I need select time in Vietnam. I will select

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + interval '7h'
```